# PKIX path building for internal CA

Tags: tomcat, ssl, https, jira

I'm trying to get a couple of applications linked together correctly in Tomcat but I'm getting the following.

```
Invalid response from getting the pageId: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
    sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
    unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I've dealt with this in the past using an internal CA without issue.

My current server.xml looks like this:

```
  <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
             ....
             keystoreFile="/jira-home/jira.example.org.p12"
             keystorePass="xxx"
             keystoreType="pkcs12"
             keyAlias="jira.example.org"
             truststoreFile="/jira-home/jira.example.org.p12"
             truststoreType="pkcs12"
             truststorePass="xxx"
             />
```

I've also verified that the command line arguments to the Java executable aren't overriding the keystore / truststore values.

My p12 file also looks good as far as I can tell.

```
Bag Attributes
    localKeyID: 47 96 87 64 A2 A0 66 C3 B7 3C 09 53 BD 22 ED 50 37 DE 62 B7
    friendlyName: jira.example.org
subject=/C=US/ST=Kansas/L=Kansas City/O=CFCA/OU=IS/CN=jira.example.org
issuer=/DC=org/DC=example/CN=example-CA2-CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIF1TCCBL2gAwIBAgIKEOfX4AAAAAAB5zANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBHMRMwEQYK
k8ThWdXWScM8
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
Bag Attributes: <No Attributes>
subject=/CN=CA2.example.org
issuer=/DC=org/DC=example/CN=example-CA2-CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIE0jCCA7qgAwIBAgIKYQCskwAAAAAIFTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBHMRMwEQYK
motn49ZLI61VXW4KrM2ZCgSOu1O5DMqLnd4DZCgHxvYwckemqDo=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
Bag Attributes: <No Attributes>
subject=/CN=OFFLINECA2-CA
issuer=/CN=OFFLINECA2-CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDMjCCAhqgAwIBAgIQIvkuOz6aNL5K+7XhjbwOMDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADAY
MF2ktx6a
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
Bag Attributes
    localKeyID: 47 96 87 64 A2 A0 66 C3 B7 3C 09 53 BD 22 ED 50 37 DE 62 B7
    friendlyName: jira.example.org
Key Attributes: <No Attributes>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

All of the other application servers I'm connecting to also are from the same intermediate and root CA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chain does not look right to me. But it could be because I'm not familiar with the output.

The image is from Peter Gutmann's [Engineering Security](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/book.pdf). Its what I expected to see.

[image]

---

Here's what I see.

#### Server

```
subject=/C=US/ST=Kansas/L=Kansas City/O=CFCA/OU=IS/CN=jira.example.org
issuer=/DC=org/DC=example/CN=example-CA2-CA
```

So the next in the chain needs a subject of `example-CA2-CA`.

#### Intermediate

```
subject=/CN=CA2.example.org
issuer=/DC=org/DC=example/CN=example-CA2-CA
```

Hmmm... What happened to subject with `CN=example-CA2-CA`?

Why is the issuer `CN=example-CA2-CA`? Shouldn't the issuer be `CN=OFFLINECA2-CA`?

#### Private CA

```
subject=/CN=OFFLINECA2-CA
issuer=/CN=OFFLINECA2-CA
```

Looks OK to me from 10,000 feet.